# Type annotation for generic (protocol) class argument

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to work out how to add a type annotation for a function argument that should be a class implementing a generic protocol.

As an example, assume I have a protocol for a set that could look something like this:

```py
from typing import (
    Protocol, TypeVar, Iterable
)

T = TypeVar('T', contravariant=True)


class Set(Protocol[T]):
    """A set of elements of type T."""

    def __init__(self, init: Iterable[T]) -> None:
        """Initialise set with init."""
        ...

    def __contains__(self, x: T) -> bool:
        """Test if x is in set."""
        ...

    def add(self, x: T) -> None:
        """Add x to the set."""
        ...

    def remove(self, x: T) -> None:
        """Remove x from the set."""
        ...
```

and I have an algorithm that uses sets of various types, that I want to parameterise with the set implementation. For simplicity I'll just create a list in this function to use as an example:

```py
from typing import Type

def foo(set_type: Type[Set]) -> None:
    """Do clever stuff."""
    x = list(range(10))
    s = set_type(x)
    ...
```

Here, `mypy` tells me that `Set` is missing a type parameter, which I suppose is correct, but I don't want to give it one, as I plan to use `set_type` with different types.

If I give `Set` a `TypeVar` instead

```py
def foo(set_type: Type[Set[T]]) -> None:
    """Do clever stuff"""
    x = list(range(10))
    s = set_type(x)
    ...
```

I instead get the warning that I `set_type()` gets an incompatible type, `List[int]` instead of `Iterable[T]`, which again is correct, but doesn't help me much.

Is there a way to specify that my function argument can be used as a generic constructor for sets of different types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Protocol` says nothing about the signature of `__init__`, even if it's defined on the `Protocol`. `Type` does a similar thing - even if `Set` isn't a `Protocol`, `Type[Set]` says nothing about how the type is called.

I initially suggested using `Callable[[Iterable[T]], Set[T]]`. However, this is problematic, and only works because I omitted the generic parameter, essentially making it `Any`, as discussed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1179). You can instead use a (rather verbose) protocol.

```
class MkSet(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, it: Iterable[T]) -> Set[T]:
        ...

def foo(set_type: MkSet) -> None:
    ...
```

Comment: @ThomasMailund it appears I made a mistake. I've updated the answer. You may also want to have a look at the github issue I raised regarding the mypy behaviour